# docusaurus about sidebars of docusaurus to multi-language

Tags: docusaurus

I use 'Docusaurus' to docs but I don`t know How to config multi-language sideBar.

````
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          path: 'docs',
          routeBasePath: '/',
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js')
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ]```

The code only use a kind of sidebars, if I switch the language The sidebars can`t switch.
````

Answer (score 1):

run the write-translations command, for example your locale is zh-cn, when command finished, you will get a `current.json` file in the `i18n/zh-cn/docusaurus-plugin-content-docs` directory

> yarn run write-translations -- --locale zh-cn

the `current.json` contains the docs sidebar's category labels, modify it like the following:

```
{
  "version.label": {
    "message": "5.0.0.alpha.1",
    "description": "The label for version current"
  },
  "sidebar.docsSidebar.category.Getting Started": {
    "message": "开始上手",
    "description": "The label for category Getting Started in sidebar docsSidebar"
  },
  "sidebar.docsSidebar.category.Guides": {
    "message": "指南",
    "description": "The label for category Guides in sidebar docsSidebar"
  }
}
```

for more details, refer to:https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/i18n/tutorial#translate-plugin-data

Answer (score 0):

Docusaurus allows you to add a `navbar item` so the user can select the language they want. You can enable the dropdown by adding the code below, as explained in [the official documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/i18n/tutorial), to the `docusaurus.config.js` file.

If you want to find out more you can also have a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/2Arz1j5n2u0) in which I explain all the steps you need to follow to translate your Docusaurus website.

```
module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    navbar: {
      items: [
        {
          type: 'localeDropdown',
          position: 'left',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> if I switch the language The sidebars can`t switch

If you properly [prepared i18n JSON files](https://docusaurus.io/docs/i18n/tutorial#translate-json-files), when you switch the locale (language), the sidebar label will show different languages.